# Apache2 memory limit

Tags: server, apache2, php

What does setting your memory limit to -1 do in php.ini for apache2.

I assume it just gives it unlimited memory but im not sure could anybody clarify? Dont want it chewing through all my memory ha!

Thanks

Comment: Hi :) Your question is a bit off topic for askubuntu and would probably be more suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com but I will try to answer your question anyway. Apache has a limited scope in how much memory you can set for scripts. 0 - 32. -1 is out of that scope, and I would imagine you would be getting some errors in your log if it was set as such.

Comment: Its an ubuntu related question though? But i see your point. I have read the documentation and figured it out so ill answer it and post on more relevant stack exchange next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is
>   allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for
>   eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no
>   memory limit, set this directive to -1.
>
> Prior to PHP 5.2.1, in order to use this directive it had to be
>   enabled at compile time by using --enable-memory-limit in the
>   configure line. This compile-time flag was also required to define the
>   functions memory_get_usage() and memory_get_peak_usage() prior to
>   5.2.1.
>
> When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand
>   notation, as described in this FAQ, may also be used.

This is a quote from php documentation. Basically its gives your php scripts access to as much memory as they need. Probably not good practice. But there you go.

Thanks 
Bill